# when I acess my accordion page I see my last accordion <h3> retracting, whe I use `active: false,`

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, accordion, jquery-ui-accordion

Im using jQuery accordion and Im having one issue.

If in my function to start jQuery, I use `active: 0,` it works fine, I have my first accordion open when I acess my accordion page.

But when I use `active: false,`, when I acess my accordion page, or when I refresh this page, Im always seeing my last accordion to retracting.

And Im trying to use `active: false,`, for when I acess my accordion page, I see all my accordions closed, but I dont want to see this retracting effect when I acess page.

Do you see why can I have wrong for this is happening?

This is my html:

```
 <div class="accordion ative">
     <h3><a href="#">Title 1</a></h3>
           <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
           </ul>
</div>         

 <div class="accordion ative">
     <h3><a href="#">Title 2</a></h3>
           <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
           </ul>
</div>
```

This is my jQuery:

```
$(function() {
   $('.accordion').accordion({
    active: 2,   
    collapsible: true,
    heightStyle: "content",
    icons: { header: 'ui-icon-plus', activeHeader: 'ui-icon-minus'}
});
$('.accordion.ative').accordion({
    active: false,   
    collapsible: true,
});

 $('.accordion.spo').accordion({
    active: 0,   
    collapsible: true, 
    heightStyle: "content",

});
});
```

Comment: Not sure why seeing the accordion retracting is a big detail to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be calling the accordions by id not class, you are initializing accordions multiple times. You jQuery class selectors will match multiple accordions. Give each accordion an id and select each accordion by #id for each accordion configuration.

```
$(function() {
  $('#accordion1').accordion({
    active: 2,   
    collapsible: true,
    heightStyle: "content",
    icons: { header: 'ui-icon-plus', activeHeader: 'ui-icon-minus'}
   });

  $('#accordion2').accordion({
     active: false,   
     collapsible: true
   });


});


    <div id="accordion1" class="accordion ative">
        <h3><a href="#">Title 1</a></h3>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div id="accordion2" class="accordion ative">
        <h3><a href="#">Title 2</a></h3>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Brian Odgen. It seems a good solution. But strangly Im having the some problem!!

Comment: Did you try using a timeout before calling $('#accordionWrapper').show();

Comment: Using a timenout before calling my wrapperno, but I tried now and issue continues!

Comment: Brian Odgen If I use only your code it is working. But I have three accordion configurations, because I need 3 diffrent options for active in my project. And when I use my 3 accordion configurations I have always my issue...Do you know why this can be happening?

Comment: You just aren't providing enough code, you will have to provide at least 2 different configurations of your accordion then, otherwise I do not understand what you are talking about enough to help

Comment: Brian Odgen thanks for trying to help. And I update my question with what I have.

Comment: You should be calling the accordions by id not class, you are initializing accordions multiple times. You jQuery class selectors will match multiple accordions. Give each accordion and id and select each accordion by #id for each accordion configuration.

Comment: I have updated my answer, this is probably why you were seeing retracting on your accordions because you were calling $.accordion more than once for each accordion.

Comment: Thank you Brian Odgen. Your solution worked perfectly. Thanks for help and explanation!